# How to symbolicate PLCrashReports for OS X Apps

Tags: macos, symbolicate, plcrashreporter

I've added PLCrashReporter to my OS X application and am successfully saving the crash dumps to a server. However, plcrashutil does not appear to symbolicate even with the .app and .dSYM in the same directory as both plcrashutil and the crash file.

I also tried following the instructions in TN 2123 for using gdb to get the address and it fails to give a source line for the symbols reported in the crash file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plcrashutil does not symbolicate, it just creates a crash file in the standard format. You'll need to use symbolicatecrash.pl from Xcode to symbolicate the report.

There is a patched version of symbolicatecrash.pl, which fixes a few bugs, available here: https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit/tree/develop/server/local

Please note, that PLCrashReporter currently does not work correctly on Intel 64Bit architecture!

But a new version with support for 64Bit is being worked on from the PLCrashReporter developers in cooperation with HockeyApp. See http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-04-27-plcrashreporter-and-unwinding-the-stack-with-dwarf.html and http://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2012/4/27/mac-os-x-sandbox-support-is-coming.html

Comment: Doesn't work at all, or doesn't work with the sandbox? I've already got it sending reports and can parse them, just no symbols.

Comment: On 64Bit the data is just plain wrong, this is not sandbox specific! The addresses are wrong, you won't be able to get any meaningful data out of it. See the linked articles, that's why there is currently additional development going on to make it work. Oh, and if you run symbolicatecrash with the output of plcrashutil, you will see what I mean. You just don't get any meaningful results, since the data is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Kerni. I thought I’m going mad after trying to get something meaningful out of some x86_64 crash logs. I wonder why the (outdated) [Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) states that there is experimental support for that architecture.